# Promises are not fetching all the data to frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb

I'm using promises to fetch some data based level, for higher level(L2) I need to fetch their records and the users who are working under their level as well. So this is what I could come up with.

```
module.exports.getQ = function(req, res) {
  var promises = [];
  var data = [];
  User.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        reportingManager: req.user.user.empId
      }
    }
  ], function(err, data) {
    if (err)
      console.log(err);
    else {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          Quotation.find({
            $or: [{
              salesCrm: data[i].empId
            }, {
              salesCrm: req.user.user.empId
            }]
          }, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              reject(err);
            } else {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
              resolve(result);
            }
          }).sort({
            createdOn: 1
          })
        }))
        Promise.all(promises).then((allInsts) => {
          res.json(allInsts[0]);
        }).catch((error) => {
        });
      }
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data) + "----------------");
    }
  })
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that in the backend it's fetching all the data properly but not in the frontend. When I refresh the page it will display some user data sometimes it won't.

[image]

Only L2's and any one of the L3's data is fetching to the front end but not all L3's data along with L2.

Can anybody help me resolve this issue?

Data that is missing :

```
[{
  "sourceLanguage": "English",
  "targetLanguage": "Telugu",
  "fuzzySlab": "New Words",
  "_id": "5b87c09660b9eb3f309f86b6",
  "fileName": "Episode 11",
  "serviceType": "Proof Reading",
  "rate": 1.25,
  "uom": "English Word",
  "quantity": 1000,
  "fileStatus": "Init"
}],
"salesCrm": "VVVV4500", 
"createdName": "Rakshith R", 
"tax": "Yes"
```

In front-end: Not displaying all the user's data.

[image]

Comment: did you check your data in nodejs ? Is it all there ?

Comment: What do you mean by *"in the backend it's fetching all the data properly but not in the frontend"*? Did you try this API out in postman? Is it responding with appropriate data there? IF yes, then please post your front-end code where you're hitting that API to get the API Response.

Comment: @SiddAjmera In console (console.log(JSON.stringify(allInsts));) it is fetching all the records(nodejs), same thing is not displaying in frontend(angular5) and displays only few records. When i refresh the page it will again display different user's data. Do i need to slow down the promises  by keeping setTimeOut untill it gets all the data. ?

Comment: @Lokesh, Yes, i have double checked it, all the records are there.

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one bug in this loop.  Promises are asynchronous, loops are synchronous.  So what is going to happen most of the time here is that you are going to loop through these.  The promises functions will be pushed into the queue to run when they can and by the time they run `i` will not be the value it was when the iteration started.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Quotation.find({
        $or: [{
          // this will be the value of i when it executes Asynchronously
          salesCrm: data[i].empId
        }, {
          salesCrm: req.user.user.empId
        }]
      },
      //... Other stuff
    }))
```

There are a couple ways to get around this, you can either use `let` in your loop and use babel or some other transpiler.

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
```

Or you can do it old school and create an immediately invoked function that will store the value as you push.  That would look something like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    function(i){(promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Quotation.find({
        $or: [{
          // this will be the value of i when it executes Asynchronously
          salesCrm: data[i].empId
        }, {
          salesCrm: req.user.user.empId
        }]
      },
      //... Other stuff
    }))}(i)
```

Notice here that we create a function so that i is in the closure and pass our current i to it so that it is stored for later.

I recommend way 1 if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use array map function to make it simpler

```
module.exports.getQ = function(req, res) {
  var promises = [];
  var data = [];

  User.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        reportingManager: req.user.user.empId
      }
    }
  ], function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    return Promise.all(data.map((item) => {
        Quotation
            .find({
                $or: [{
                    salesCrm: item.empId
                }, {
                    salesCrm: req.user.user.empId
                }]
            }, function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    return reject(err);
                }

                return resolve(result);
            })
            .sort({
                createdOn: 1
            })
    }))
    .then((allInsts) => {
      res.json(allInsts[0]);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
    });
})
```

}